# How to get an Android Camera2 with 1:1 ratio like Instagram?

Tags: android, android-camera2

My question is very simple:

> How to get an Android `android.hardware.Camera2` with 1:1 ratio and without deformation like Instagram?

I tested with the GoogeSamples project [android-Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic). But when I change the preview with a ratio of 1:1 image is deformed. Does anyone have an idea on this?

[image]

Comment: "But when I change the preview with a ratio of 1:1 image is deformed" -- we cannot help you debug your code unless you provide your code, as part of a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In general, the answer is to have the `SurfaceView` or `TextureView` be the same aspect ratio as the image off of the camera, but then use negative margins or equivalent rendering tricks to only show a square subset of what comes in from the camera.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare. Use negative margins correct my problem. I post my code in answer.

Comment: @lopez.mikhael how do you changed the aspect ratio? take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221284/how-to-change-aspect-ratio-of-camera2-preview

Comment: @lopez.mikhael: I want to implement it in a similar way, how did you set the aspect ration to 1:1 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks @CommonsWare.

I followed your advice using negative margin (top and bottom) and it works.

To do that, I just update [AutoFitTextureView](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) the GoogeSamples project [android-Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) this way:

```
public class AutoFitTextureView extends TextureView {

    //...
    private boolean mWithMargin = false;

    //...

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        int margin = (height - width) / 2;

        if(!mWithMargin) {
            mWithMargin = true;
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams margins = ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.class.cast(getLayoutParams());
            margins.topMargin = -margin;
            margins.bottomMargin = -margin;
            margins.leftMargin = 0;
            margins.rightMargin = 0;
            setLayoutParams(margins);
        }

        if (0 == mRatioWidth || 0 == mRatioHeight) {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else {
            if (width < height) {
                setMeasuredDimension(width, width * mRatioHeight / mRatioWidth);
            } else {
                setMeasuredDimension(height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight, height);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi!
I have the same problem. I add your implementation of AutoFitTextureView, but it is still does't work. can u please provide some more code of you app to make camera preview and pictures in square way?

thanks!

Comment: when i do this, i get a black bar at the bottom of the preview.. any ideas?

Comment: @lopez.mikhael in your code `super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);` is this line intentional or the 2nd param should be height? And even if I change it your solution doesn't work. Please provide an updated answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create custom texture view like this:

```
public class AutoFitTextureView extends TextureView {

    private int mCameraWidth = 0;
    private int mCameraHeight = 0;
    private boolean mSquarePreview = false;

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setAspectRatio(int width, int height, boolean squarePreview) {
        if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot be negative.");
        }
        mCameraWidth = width;
        mCameraHeight = height;
        mSquarePreview = squarePreview;
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (0 == mCameraWidth || 0 == mCameraHeight) {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else {
            /**
             * Vertical orientation
             */
            if (width < height) {
                if (mSquarePreview) {
                    setTransform(squareTransform(width, height));
                    setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
                } else {
                    setMeasuredDimension(width, width * mCameraHeight / mCameraWidth);
                }
            }
            /**
             * Horizontal orientation
             */
            else {
                if (mSquarePreview) {
                    setTransform(squareTransform(width, height));
                    setMeasuredDimension(height, height);
                } else {
                    setMeasuredDimension(height * mCameraWidth / mCameraHeight, height);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private Matrix setupTransform(int sw, int sh, int dw, int dh) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        RectF src = new RectF(0, 0, sw, sh);
        RectF dst = new RectF(0, 0, dw, dh);
        RectF screen = new RectF(0, 0, dw, dh);

        matrix.postRotate(-90, screen.centerX(), screen.centerY());
        matrix.mapRect(dst);

        matrix.setRectToRect(src, dst, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
        matrix.mapRect(src);

        matrix.setRectToRect(screen, src, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        matrix.postRotate(-90, screen.centerX(), screen.centerY());

        return matrix;
    }

    private Matrix squareTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        if (viewWidth < viewHeight) {
            MyLogger.log(AutoFitTextureView.class, "Horizontal");
            matrix.setScale(1, (float) mCameraHeight / (float) mCameraWidth, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);
        } else {
            MyLogger.log(AutoFitTextureView.class, "Vertical");
            matrix.setScale((float) mCameraHeight / (float) mCameraWidth, 1, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);
        }

        return matrix;
    }
}
```

And call setAspectRatio for your texture view in activity/fragment.

```
if (mVideoSize.width > mVideoSize.height) {
    mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mVideoSize.height, mVideoSize.width, true);
} else {
    mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mVideoSize.width, mVideoSize.height, true);
}
mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture());
mCamera.startPreview();
```

Comment: Hi Mikhael! I try to implement your solution but doesn't work. Could you post or send me a complete implementation please? it will be fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

I did it with the Layout, in that way, google code can be keeped as it comes and automatically set a 1:1 preview based on the UI.

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@id/header">

    <com.example.android.camera2video.AutoFitTextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Just put the AutoFitTextureView inside a ConstraintLayout and then

`previewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                    width, height, videoSize);`

does all the magic

Comment: What is ```videoSize``` here?

Answer (score 1):

For anybody looking for this, I tried the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34650699/5105754). Adding a margin to hide part of textureview to make it look square  looks good in preview. But when saving the image, you should remove the hidden areas from the output image also.

An Easier solution is to show a full textureview and to overlay some other layouts on it to make it look square.You can easily crop the image from output.

you can find the sample code [here](https://github.com/tomsaju/Square-camera)